# Get the result value from an observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, redux-observable

I am using an angular 12 project.

I have an observable:

```js
     export class RegisterUserShellComponent implements OnInit {

       constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

       user$: Observable<User>;
       isNull$: Observable<Boolean>; 

       ngOnInit(): void {
            this.user$ = this.store.select(getSelectedUser);
       }
      
     }
```

Here is the User class definition:

```js
    export interface User {
        id: string | null;
        name: String;
        socialMedia: SocialMedia;
        companyName: string;
    }
```

I need to get the value from user$, check if it is null or not and assign it to isNull$.

My question is how can I read a property from the value user$ stream to process the value (to check if it is null or not) and assign the result to isNull$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rxjs, there is no need to manually subscribe. This solution also keeps `isNull$` as an observable.

```
this.user$ = this.store.select(getSelectedUser);
this.isNull$ = this.user$.pipe(map(user => user === null));
```

Then (if relevant) use the`async` pipe against each observable in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `this.store.select(getSelectedUser)` returns an observable, you could then subscribe to it, check if a value is returned, and set `isNull$` to be an observable using `of()` with the boolean of that check.

```js
    export class RegisterUserShellComponent implements OnInit {
    
       constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }
    
       user$: Observable<User>;
       isNull$: Observable<Boolean>; 
    
       ngOnInit(): void {
            this.user$ = this.store.select(getSelectedUser);
            this.user$.subscribe(user => this.isNull$ = of(!!user))
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, what is the meaning for you!! operator?

Answer (score 1):

To get the result from an observable within a component just `subscribe`. I'm not sure why you declared `isNull` as an `observable` if you're going to assign a boolean to it, so I'm going to assume that was a mistake.

```js
export class RegisterUserShellComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

    user$: Observable<User>;
    isNull: boolean; 

    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.user$ = this.store.select(getSelectedUser);
         this.user$.subscribe((user) => (this.isNull = !!user));
    }
      
}
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: I was going to type this exact same answer, lol. Was not sure if there was a requirement to keep isNull an observable. Nice answer!

Comment: lol yours as well